# Como intercalar os valores de duas filas em C, em uma terceira fila?

Tags: c, array, funções, estrutura-de-dados, fila

Estou tentando intercalar os valores de duas filas em C, f1 e f2, em uma terceira Fila, Inter, conforme função abaixo (n seria a quantidade de elementos de f1 e de f2):

```
Fila *intercala_fila (Fila *f1, Fila *f2){
   int Tam, i;
   Fila *Inter = fila_cria();

   Tam = f1->n + f2->n;

   for(i=0;i<Tam;i++){
      fila_insere(Inter, f1->vet[i]);
      fila_insere(Inter, f2->vet[i]);
   }

   return Inter; }
```

Estou conseguindo intercalar com sucesso, porém, estou obtendo lixo de memória no resultado, conforme abaixo:

```
10 //valor de f1
3 //valor de f2
5 //valor de f1
8 //valor de f2
2 //valor de f1
//abaixo são printados os lixos de memória
1297903728
1275095411
1464299113
1279345487
1650209846
```

Como posso obter um resultado em que eu consiga intercalar os valores de ambas as filas sem obter valores da memória, ou então sem omitir valores de f1 ou f2?

Obrigada!

Comment: Mas qual a definição de sua Fila? A princípio não me parece correto somar a quantidade de elementos da duas filas e tentar acessar tal quantidade em cada uma delas.

Comment: O seu laço for vai até Tam (que é a soma do tamanho das duas filas), mas as filas f1 e f2 são menores que Tam

Answer (score 1):

`Tam` não deve ser a soma de `f1->n` e `f2->n`, mas sim igual ao número de elementos da maior fila (`maximo(f1->n, f2->n)`). (Então seria melhor você mudar o nome dessa variável `Tam` já que ela não representa o tamanho final da lista intercalada.)

E só deve inserir se ainda tiver items na lista para serem inseridos, então tem que checar que o contador `i` é menor que o número de elementos da lista antes de inserir esse elemento na lista intercalada.

```
Fila *intercala_fila (Fila *f1, Fila *f2){
    int Tam, i;
    Fila *Inter = fila_cria();

    //Tam eh igual ao numero de elementos da maior fila:
    Tam = f1->n > f2->n ? f1->n : f2->n;

    for(i=0;i<Tam;i++){
        //Deve inserir somente se ainda tem items na fila:
        if(i < f1->n) fila_insere(Inter, f1->vet[i]);
        if(i < f2->n) fila_insere(Inter, f2->vet[i]);
    }

    return Inter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que estes lixos de memória na fila `inter` venham das filas `f1` e `f2`. Ao fazer alguns testes, cheguei em uma solução meio ruim, mas a principio já gera um resultado diferente. O que foi feito foi modificar o valor `n` da fila `inter` para o valor final do contador `i`, com isso, ao chamar uma função para mostrar a fila `inter`, ela não pegaria e mostraria estes lixos, mas lembrando que eles ainda existem lá.

```
Fila *intercala_fila (Fila *f1, Fila *f2){
    Fila *inter=fila_cria();//cria fila inter
    int tamanho=f1->n+f2->n;//soma o tamanho das filas f1 e f2 a partir do valor de seu fim
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=tamanho;i++){//for que roda até o tamanho da soma de f1 e f2
        fila_insere(inter, f1->vet[i]);//insere valores de f1 e f2 intercaladamente
        fila_insere(inter, f2->vet[i]);
    }
    inter->n=i-1;//determina que o fim da fila inter é igual ao valor final do contador
                 //para que assim não sejam impressos lixos de memória presentes na  fila inter
    return inter;//retorna fila inter
}
```